# publish mvc 3 application to localhost and connect to localhost sql server database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have published the mvc 3 application to the IIS 7 localhost. I have use Entity Framework 4 database first. While publishing application the .mdf file is placed under **App_Data** folder of **wwwroot/mvc3applciation** . In practical how do I connect to the localhost sql server 2008 not to the .mdf file of App_Data and after that does the entity framework work fine. What I have to configure to connect to localhost database server to my mvc 3 application that works with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

in the `<connectionStrings>` setting of your web config you need to add an entry which has the same name as your `DbContext` and specify the database server and instance, something like:

```
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. I have try this and got error in configuration for provider : 
 <providers>
      <clear />
        <add name="IVRControlPanelRoleProvider" type="IVRControlPanel.Helpers.IVRControlPanelRoleProvider" connectionStringName="IVRControlPanelEntities" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>

Comment: I am not sure what the IVRControlPanelRoleProvider is, I assume that is something custom / third party that you are using in your webconfig.  Have you tried first using the simple providers from a default MVC project.